# Options for a simple window manager besides kwin?

Tags: window-managers

I'm making a "sealed" system here for a kiddies school, and at the moment I'm programming in python (PyQt) and hacked the other things (including the bios) in order to obtain a "sealed", system that only does what I want it to do. No option to run commands/boot devices, etc. The function keys and combinations on keyboard were mapped off. And, file permissions were carefully chosen to allow the system to run only what I want.

The problem is, it's an atom device, which has quite poor specs, and I'm using the window manager kwin from KDE to make the graphics, along with Qt4 (PyQt4), however, I want to make the gui in C++ with possibly wxwidgets, or even java (2GB of ram) using swing or something, so I want a light and minimal window manager.

The problem is i just can't find a really small and minimalist pure window manager for that purpose. I don't want to run kwin because i needed to hack it a lot, because it was asking about errors and I don't have the time to remove the checks. Also, it's not light and I'm not going to use Qt.

I thought something like 'window maker' would help, but it comes with lots of features that I will never use, and only adds complexity to the whole thing. More stuff to "block".

I just want something that simply creates windows, nothing more. Something like kwin, but light, no need for seamless Qt, and that runs stand-alone without too much hacking.

Any recommendations?

Thank you.

PS: It's for charity. Cheap linux pcs for kiddies, mostly to learn the basics of browsers, document editing, etc. It doesn't have a name nor webpage yet, but i have lots of work to do, because i plan to "hack" the apps to make them behave properly and seamlessly. Mostly to remove menus/shortcuts.

Comment: Have you tried any other window managers like blackbox, openbox, twm? Have you come across this in your searches? http://xwinman.org/

Comment: @FrankHale yep. I didn't try all of them, but I think they wouldn't quite suit my needs. I ended up using KWin and it was not that bad because I also decide to use PyQt (Python) for a lot of things that would take much more time to do in C++. The project stalled though :(. Thank you.